# Codeigniter: Models not working with an error: Undefined property: CI_Loader

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying out making a simple API with Codeigniter, which is supposed to do basic CRUD tasks on the database related with the form inputs from the main website. I'm mostly a frontend person and don't really have an in-depth knowledge with PHP. It's my first time using the Codeigniter. I'm starting with trying out things on the documentation website, but I ran into a problem working with models.

before actually working with databases, I tried writing a really simple model that just returns "Model_form_receipt" when called. The website gives me an `Undefined property: CI_Loader` error. This is really troubling because I don't think I even deviated much from the samples from the documentation; perhaps even simpler. Do you have any idea on the cause of this issue and a solution?

The model file (models/Model_form_receipt.php)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_form_receipt extends CI_Model {
  public function test()  {
    return "Model_form_receipt";
  }
}
?>
```

The view file

```
<?php
$this->load->model('model_form_receipt');
$data = $this->model_form_receipt->test();
?>
```

Error Messages

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$model_form_receipt

Filename: form_receipt/base.php

Line Number: 3
```

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function test() on null

Filename: [REDACTED]

Line Number: 3
```

Comment: you have to load model in controller.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Uh... okay that solved it. Thanks much. Can't believe I wasted hours on this. :P

Comment: please set a controller, and load the model in controller ,not in a view file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Your Controller**

**Autoload the model in __construct function.

Thus, your model will run automatically in your function**

**It could help**

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Model_form_receipt');
}
```